# What represents the HttpStatus of a ResponseEntity object in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc

in the Spring MVC Showcase example dowlodable from the STS dashboard

I have some doubt about the following situation:

In my view I have the following link:

```
        <li>
            <a id="responseEntityStatus" class="textLink" href="<c:url value="/response/entity/status" />">ResponseEntity (custom status)</a>           
        </li>
```

This link generate an HTTP Request towards the URL: "/response/entity/status"

This URL is handled by the following method of a @Controller class named **ResponseController** (which in turn is annotated with @RequestMapping(value="/response", method=RequestMethod.GET) )

The method thath handled the previus HTTP Request is:

```
@RequestMapping("/entity/status")
public ResponseEntity<String> responseEntityStatusCode() {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("The String ResponseBody with custom status code (403 Forbidden)",
            HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
}
```

This method return a **ResponseEntity** object and, reading the documentation, I understand that returning a setted ResponseEntity objct is substantially the same thing as a return a **@ResponseBody String** object

So, in my particular case, I am returning a ResponseEntity object (that rappresent my HTTP Response) in wicht I have setted the

1. **HTTP RESPONSE Body field** with the String **The String ResponseBody with custom status code (403 Forbidden)**
2. **I have not setted Headers fields**
3. **I have setted the HTTP Status status code to HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN**

Now, I have read that this HttpStatus is a field of ResponseEntity class but I have not understand what this object exactly rappresent...

So what rappresent the HttpStatus object? and what mean if it is setted to FORBIDDEN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpStatus is not an object, it's a [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) that contains an enumeration of [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). The FORBIDDEN status represent the [HTTP 403 status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)